# Exercise of odd and even [If-Else]

Tags: python

Exercise of odd and even [If-Else], conditions:

1. If n is odd, print weird.
2. If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 and 5, print Not Weird
3. If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 and 20, print weird
4. If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird

A and D can be the same as

```
if n%2==0:
print("Not Weird")

else:
print("Weird")
```

So now I have to play around with conditions *2* and *3*.
I tried to put in

```
if n%2==0 or n in range (2,6):
    print("Not Weird")

elif n in range (6,21):
    print("Weird")
```

Works fine, but I'm having problems with the range between 2 and 6.
If anyone can explain me how to do it and the logic behind it I would appreciate it.

Comment: For "B" you have "If n is even ***and*** in the inclusive range of 2 and 5, print Not Weird" (emphasis mine). Think a little more about it...

Comment: If the assignment is to handle *all* cases, then I suggest you try to find some commonality between all the four cases.  For this it seems to be if `n` is even or odd. Start with that *only*. Then for B, C and D you only have to modify the path taken when `n` is even, and you can add these as a new nested `if` inside the even path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your conditions into python code:

```
if (n%2==0) and (n in range(2,6) or n > 20): #Conditions B and D
    print('Not Weird')
elif (n%2 == 1) or (n%2 == 0 and n in range(6, 21)): #Conditions A and C
    print('Weird')
```

However since they are mutually exclusive you can just use and `if-else` statement

```
if (n%2==0) and (n in range(2,6) or n > 20): #Conditions B and D
    print('Not Weird')
else:
    print('Weird')
```

Comment: Perfect, this is the right answer, I didn't know you can call (n%2==0 and n in range(6,21)) looking at examples it opens my mind. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 8

if (n % 2 == 0 or n in range(2, 6)) and n not in range(6, 21):
    print("Not Weird")

elif n in range(6, 21):
    print("Weird")
```

Comment: It's wrong, the code doesn't work well with the numbers below 6.
If I try to input 1: It will not show anything.
If I try to input 2, 3, 4, 5: Not Weird.

Comment: if you need to include 6 in 'Not Weird', the range  must be redefined as below n = 8

if (n % 2 == 0 or n in range(2, 7)) and n not in range(7, 21):
    print("Not Weird")

elif n in range(6, 21):
    print("Weird")

Comment: The problem is not only 6, is with 4 as well.